# ToolStripSplitButton Customization

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

Does anyone know how I can move the 'Split' portion of a ToolStripSplitButton to the bottom of the button instead of the side?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this does not work by default. I guess you'd have to create your own ToolStripItem class.

Comment: I have tried creating a class derived from ToolStripSplitButton, and can't seem to find the correct overrides to pull this off.

I am hoping not to have to go all the way down to the ToolStripItem level, but I guess maybe that is the only option here.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. Probably you'll have to override the painting/mouse handling routines only? If all else fails, there's always .NET Reflector to inspect the code for ToolStripSplitButton ;-)